# My system is freezing regularly for at least 15 to 20 mins

Tags: freeze

I need some advice to solve my issue. I dont what went wrong in my system. recently it started to hang/freeze about 15 to 20 mins. then it will be free to work for less than 10 mins and again it will freeze. I totally fed up to work.

So i started to work in safe mode in the same system which is not hanging at all.
But some softwares are not working since the services will not start in safe mode.

I dont want to format my system. I tried sfc/ scannow, chkdsk methods. No result.

Can any one please suggest some idea to solve this issue.

Regards,
Ramkumar.

Comment: Is absolutely everything freezing, mouse, keyboard, even caps log/num lock lights on the keyboard? Safe mode disables lots of hardware drivers, so maybe/probably some driver is causing problems, any driver updates you can roll back? Or new hardware lately?

Comment: Does your tempreature optimal and not very high for processor? and for video card ?

Comment: Hi user1448914,

Thanks for your reply.

Ya as you said, every thing is freezing (Mouse, Key board, everything). No any new updates. Actually i have un installed many applications after this problem ariased.

Comment: That is actually stranger that it would *unfreeze* at all... maybe it is related to heat somehow, cleaning out dust shouldn't hurt, or maybe some hardware is failing, but in safe mode it doesn't get used so doesn't affect anything

Comment: But many suggest to try Format once. But i don want to do that. If nothing works, then last step would be that only.

Answer (score 0):

You write nothing about your computer.

At first, find the system logs and see what the last entries are. Try to deduce the last things which occurred. You have observed the freeze several times. What have you done just before the freeze ?

It's probably never a bad idea to test the RAM memory, to run a SMART selftest on the disks and to test the file systems.